# The probability of a single dice Vs many dice

Tags: probability

Say I have a fair six sided die. I throw 6 times. What's the probability the result will be 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order?

And imagine I have 6 die and threw them at the same time. What's the probability that I'll get those numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 when I arrange them?

I'm struggling to understand the difference here.

Comment: You say you are struggling to understand the difference. Does your intuition tell you that the two probabilities should be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Case 1***:  The chance you throw a $1$ on the first die is $1/6$;  the chance you throw a $2$ on the second die is also $1/6$;  and likewise for all 6 of them.  Thus the probability you get all these independent events is $P = \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^6$.

***Case 2***:  You roll the first die and it comes up with some number.  The probability that the next ("neighbor") or "second" die is some different number is $5/6$.  The probability that the third die is a number different from the prior two is $4/6$.

Can you continue?

Comment: Case 2 is confusing. Will the probabilities multiply to get the final probability?

Comment: Yes... multiplying these probabilities *will* give you the final answer.  What is your conceptual difficulty here?

Comment: Thanks. Would I be correct in saying that the total number of possible outcomes is the same in both cases?

Comment: Multiply out to see that *absolutely not*!

Comment: Well in case 1: I see that rolling the dice 6 times one after the other gives 6**3 possibilities. Is that right?

Comment: But in case 2 I just don't see how it's different in terms of the total possible outcomes